# C# Method to return the part of string

Tags: c#, .net

I am using c# .net 2.0.

I have got below string with me

```
string str = "tcm:0-433-1";
```

Now I want to create a method in C#, which will take above string as input parameter and will return `"tcm:433-"`.

Please suggest the best way for it!

Comment: why create when you can use existing one?

Comment: The returned is not _part_ of the original string. It is a composite of _several_ parts.

Comment: Is it the positions or the values you are trying to remove from the first string?

Comment: Whats the criteria of substring search?

Comment: As @Abdul is asking - what are the rules for extracting the different parts and what are the rules for combining them back together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: Here's a bit of a nutty idea. One possible way of describing your desired input/output (to me) is this: you want to *take* everything up to and including the `:` character, then skip up through the first `-` character, then take again up through the *following* `-` character.

Generalizing this idea, I came up with the following mess:

```
// Awful name, obviously.
public static string TakeSkipTakeEtc(this string source, params char[] tokens)
{
    bool taking = true;

    int startIndex = 0;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char token in tokens)
    {
        int index = source.IndexOf(token, startIndex);
        if (index == -1)
        {
            if (taking)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(source.Substring(startIndex));
            }

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }

        if (taking)
        {
            int length = index + 1 - startIndex;
            stringBuilder.Append(source.Substring(startIndex, length));
        }

        startIndex = index + 1;
        taking = !taking;
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

This extension method on `string` takes a variable number of `char` arguments, which it uses to employ basically the same logic (take through *A*, then skip through *B*, then take through *C*, etc.) for any arguments.

So, for example:

```
Console.WriteLine("tcm:0-433-1".TakeSkipTakeEtc(':', '-', '-'));
```

The above outputs:

```
tcm:433-
```

Is this probably an overly complex solution to your problem? Most likely. But hey, it was a fun little challenge (I don't get enough of those these days).

---

So, given your particular input and desired output, you could do something like:

```
return str.Substring(0, 4) + str.Substring(6, 4);
```

Obviously, this is a very shaky solution that requires its input to match a specific format (at the very least, it needs to be 10 characters long). If your input is going to be too dynamic for such a rigid approach, you might consider using `string.IndexOf` to search for key split characters or possibly even the `Regex` class (*yikes!*) to achieve your desired result.

<strike>In this particular case you could use `string.IndexOf` to find the location of the first `-` character and then `string.Substring` to take only the portion of the string up to that index.</strike>

Answer (score 5):

```
result = Regex.Replace(input, @"^(.+:)\d-(\d+-).*$", "$1$2");
```

Explaining the regular expression:

- `^` -> Start of string
- `.+` -> anything one or more times
- `(.+:)` -> first grouping
- `\d-` -> a digit followed by dash
- `\d+` -> a digit one or more times
- `$` -> end of string
- `$1$2` -> first and second grouping

Comment: This is kind of hitting the nail with a sledgehammer.

Comment: +1 for another correct solution; however you need to either use a literal string (prefix it with `@`) or escape the `\`-characters

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to show us more input/output examples, so that we can understand better the rule. Based on your one example, this would do it:

```
string str = "tcm:0-433-1";

int token1 = str.IndexOf(":");
int token2 = str.IndexOf("-");
int token3 = str.LastIndexOf("-");

if (token1 == -1 || token2 == -1 || token3 == -1)
    throw new YourException("invalid input");

string result = str.Substring(0, token1) + 
                str.Substring(token2 + 1, token3 - token2);
```

Comment: +1 if you replace `str.Substring(1, token1)` by `str.Substring(0, token1)` :-)

Comment: Just did! It was late at night... :)